# Tic Tac Toe using Machine Learning with LMS rule

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to implement the famous game of [Tic Tac Toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) using Machine learning with Least Mean Square (LMS) rule (an exercise proposed in Tom Mitchell's famous book, [Machine Learning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070428077)).

I made the computer learn by playing against an optimal opponent that picks the best moves, and then against a randomized player. Against the optimal opponent, my program won about 90% of the games and tied the rest without ever losing. Against a random opponent, it won about 83% and lost 15% of the games.

However, when I played against the program, I won every time using the same strategy.

Here's how my program works:
 * create learner and player(randomized or optimal)
 * while (game running)
 * generate all possible states for a turn and use the best to make the turn
 * the best turn is saved
 * go through saved boards and calculate value for every feature
 * calculate board score using features and current weights
 * calculate training score:
   * if last board and won: trainings value of last board == 100
   * if last board and lost: trainings value of last board: -100
 * adjust the weights using LMS rule

I expect this approach to make the computer play perfectly (win most of the time, tie otherwise)? Am I wrong, or is there something wrong with my training method?

Thoughts, ideas, code, suggestions on board features to use on this matter are really appreciated.

Comment: Tic tac toe is solvable with a very short search.  What features are you proposing to gather?  Given that the number of board positions is small, one could simply create sufficient features to programmatically solve this.  Machine learning is not only unnecessary here, but also inappropriate.

Comment: I know the state space is small enough for a brute force, but i want to see if Machine Learning can be done here, this was posted as an exercise in Tom Mitchell's book (Machine Learning), and to put my answer in a different way, Is it possible to select certain board features so the learning algorithm can learn to play the game perfectly ?

Comment: Yes: the board configuration, up to rotation, can be stored and the game can be played perfectly.  I only need a small table of features to describe the board position "classes", make membership in a class a feature, and then score the changes between classes.

Comment: "Against the optimal opponent, my program won about 90% of the games" - pretty sure that's not an optimal opponent.

Comment: The final program was able to draw when playing first against any opponent (event human) but failed in a single situation when a human player starts first and plays in the middle spot then in a corner, but i have been informed (but i am not sure if this is true) that a modification could be made to avoid this and enable the program to play perfectly, but i don't have the necessary time to look into this (if you wish "rob mayoff") i could send you my code to look at it. and thanks for your reply.

Comment: The question as it is asked is too broad. If you reformat your pseudo-code, and ask narrower questions in terms of LMS and its use in your program, you will get some answers or pointers to other comparable attempts

Comment: @RamNarasimhan, thanks for your response, but this is a very old question of mine, from college days, and i really can't remember much about AI or LMS :).

Comment: As rob mayoff noticed correctly, your optimal opponent for sure isn't optimal (or there's some other bug in your program), as the optimal strategy for tic tac toe never loses. However, when generating training data only from a single opponent using the same strategy all the time, you might overfit to that strategy. Instead, for tic tac toe it makes sense to generate all training data using random plays.

Comment: What is the space of the weights for LMS? I'm pretty sure you are not using a sufficiently complex feature space for the task. But I can't help you unless you specify exactly.

Comment: @Memming thanks for your response, but this is a very old question of mine, from college days. Anyway I remember I used multiple combinations of small and complex feature spaces but nothing did the work 100%, and as I remember our professor told us back then that this what we arrived at was the top of what LMS could do with Tic Tac Toe.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar project to this in my senior year at Lehigh, in 1968-1969, when computers ran on water.  ;-)  One module was an optimal player, and the second module was the learning machine.  In the best situation, the learning machine achieved perfect play in a very short number of training games.  To make things more interesting, I also inserted a control to have the "optimal" player make random errors, at a rate I could control.  I could then measure the rate of learning vs. the "intelligence" of the training partner (no longer optimal).  Of significance, the learning machine still managed to become an optimal player, albeit in a bit longer time.  Although a trivial game, when one extends the concept along philosophical lines, it does suggest that computers will eventually become much more highly intelligent than their "teachers."